# Advantages of using addOption with OptionBuilder in Apache Commons CLI

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I have been learning how to use Apache commons CLI. I want to use the options class to describe the possible options for a command-line, but I have seen in some tutorials that they use two ways to add a new option.

The first is this:

```java
options.addOption( OptionBuilder.withLongOpt( "block-size" )
                        .withDescription( "use SIZE-byte blocks" )
                        .hasArg()
                        .withArgName("SIZE")
                        .create() );
```

And the second way is this:

```java
options.addOption( "C", false, "list entries by columns" );
```

My question is: What would be the benefit of using the `OptionBuilder` class like in the  first example instead of using the second one?

Comment: By the way, please consider [formatting your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) as it's easier to read that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Options.addOption(...)` provides some parameter combinations, like `String opt, String longOpt, boolean hasArg, String description`. Using `Options.addOption(...)` is obviously more convenient than using an `OptionBuilder`.

However, `OptionBuilder` provides additional parameters like `hasArgs(int num)`, `isRequired`, `withType`, `withValueSeparator` and so on, which are not available using `Options.addOption(...)`. If you need them, you have to use `OptionBuilder`.

So, there is no advantage of using `Options.addOption(...)` except for more concise code (easier in reading and writing). I'd suggest you can use either, but stay consistent: If your code requires `OptionBuilder`, it's easier for the reader if you always use `OptionBuilder`, even for options which do not require it.

**Background**: The pattern used here is the **Builder Pattern**, which is used for creating classes with a great variety of properties, possibly often having a lot of unused (default) properties

[Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

[JavaWorld Link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html?null)